# Does the memory bus span multiple layers on die?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cpu, computer-architecture

My question is if you take **any model desktop CPU** such as the ones manufactured by Intel would the design of the memory bus span multiple layers of a single die or would it be contained on a single layer ? I'm assuming that if the memory bus spans multiple layers on die the CPU cores themselves also will span multiple layers also. Please feel free to correct this understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Individual layers on a die provide specific things like power, wiring (often in only one direction) or transistors. For a component to exist on a single layer it would have to be composed only of power lines, only of unpowered transistors not connected by wires, etc.

Any complicated (or even not complicated) component of a CPU will use all or nearly all layers.

Comment: Thank you @user1850479. Would you be able to clarify whether a CPU Core be considered a complicated component therefore it should span nearly all layers of the die ?

Comment: Thank you @user1850479 What about the memory bus will this component span multiple layers in order to interface with a Core ?

Comment: @JoeT Does your CPU contain transistors? If so, see above.

Comment: user1850479@ yes it does thank you.